# Web Application - Data Importing

Tags: java, excel, spring, servlets, web-applications

I am building a web application which imports excel sheets into database, later we can retreive information using search option.
Eg: I upload results of students in an excel having student id's, Physics, Chemistry and Maths marks, i have to provide two functionalities:

1. search using `id` - returns all the marks Phy, chemistry and Maths
2. search using `id` and `subject name` - returns only the subject marks

What i have done:

I used apache `poi` api for parsing the excel and created table for every excel sheet and case (1) is working fine

How to work for (2)?
I used `jsp` and `servlets` for this, which technology is better than `jsp` for this ?

Comment: Don't create a separate table for each spreadsheet. Your queries will become cumbersome and unwieldy. Use one table and import all sheets into that. Use a couple of columns to identify which sheet each row has come from.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with PHP if you want - it should be simple and straight forward - you will find many examples online. I don't think there is a particular technology for this - since your requirements are very simple.

Now if you required to have huge data sets - millions or billions of records then you will have to investigate and make very careful deliberate choice, but for your needs a simple PHP page will do just fine.